# 4- dimensional space geometry, what is the point?

Tags: geometry, spacetime-dimensions, visualization

I just read about the 4 dimensional space. I found a nice [article](http://eusebeia.dyndns.org/4d/vis/01-intro) describing how to visualize a 4-D object into our 3-D world. This is really fascinating.

However, what's the point of researching in this area? Is there any practical use of the 4-D space objects?

Comment: Four dimensional manifolds are extremely interesting in physics, because our spacetime seems to be such a thing (3+1 dimensions). Hence doing general relativity or quantum field theory needs four dimensions. It's unimportant to visualize them though. Outside physics, they are very interesting for many reasons, but that's maths.

Comment: I assume what the OP asked about was 4 spatial dimensions, rather than 3+1d (4d object). This would include things like hypercubes and hyperspheres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly has the POTENTIAL to be useful. It is entirely possible, and partially theorized, that our universe is comprised of additional dimensions and we can only perceive three spatial and one time dimension. Some variants of string theory, such as [M-Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_M-theory) propose up to 11 spatial dimensions.

If it is indeed the case that there are additional spatial dimensions, then it would be extremely 'useful' and 'practical' to research and visualize these fields. Another use of the research is to develop tests that may determine if we are existing in n-dimensional space or not, and if we are, how (if at all) we could interact with them.

If you haven't seen/read [Flatland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatland), the plot consists of hypothetical beings living in lesser dimensions.

You can watch one of the movies based on the book: http://flatlandthemovie.com/

Comment: Yes, and although the default assumption in string theory is that the extra dimensions are "curled up" at very tiny scales so we can't perceive them (analogous to how a universe that appeared 1-dimensional on large scales might actually be more like the 2D surface of a long tube, but with the circular dimension having a microscopic size), there are some theories of [large extra dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_extra_dimension) in which our 3D space could be a "brane" in a higher-dimensional space, with all particles except gravitons confined to move on the brane.

Comment: String theory is by no means the exclusive proposer of extra dimensions. Some multiverse theories utilize them as well, but regardless of what theory is actually proposing it, we may be living in more than 3+1 dimensions, and it's important to test whether this is so.

Comment: What multiverse theory are you thinking of? The many-worlds interpretation and the inflationary multiverse don't require extra dimensions as far as I know, and although [brane cosmology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brane_cosmology) might allow for multiple parallel brane-universes, it's based on M-theory which is an extension of string theory.

Comment: I'm not thinking of any in particular, but brane cosmology was what I was alluding to. In short, even if M-Theory turns out to be not the correct model of our universe, we still be living in more than 3+1 dimensions, and it's worthwhile to test whether or not this is the case and the potential implications thereof.

Comment: could be living*

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting article however it fails to take into account our ability to perceive the depth  of something which is obviously quite a big factor , the 4th dimension is just something created to try and explain the universe or explain why we cant explain the universe, there is no real reason for creating another dimension that has no effect on our 3d universe at all except than to feed the imagination. This is my opinion and everyone is entitled to there own, this is just mine. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_perception

Comment: So it's just an interesting way to look at the world and it might help us or not in understanding the universe.

Comment: Yes in reality though i can't see it being helpful to us at all if we can not perceive it or measure it or even see its effect on anything else